# How to count file difference between local directory and remote directory using lftp?

Tags: linux, ftp, lftp

I am creating a script where I want to upload files from local directory to remote directory but based on some condition I am calculating the files count and upload the files.

So I need file difference count to finish my script.

`diff -q dir1/ dir2/ | wc -l` is working fine in local but that same command is not working with lftp

```
lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no; diff -q /XXXXX/Y/ tmp/A_000/ | wc -l; bye" -u username,password remote_storage_url
```

where /XXXXX/Y/ is the remote path and tmp/A_000/ is my local path.

Well diff command is not supported command in lftp but I need solution for this issue.

Edit-1:

I have tried mirror command with --dry-run, but the problem is the actual command shows how many files are transferred and --dry-run does not shows it.

With actual run:

```
jayesh@ubuntu:~/test$ lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no; mirror -R tmp/A_000/ /XXXXX/Y/ ; bye" -u username,password remote_storage_url
New: 11 files, 0 symlinks                                                                    
19046373 bytes transferred in 50 seconds (371.8 KiB/s)
To be removed: 0 directories, 11 files, 0 symlinks
```

With --dry-run:

```
jayesh@ubuntu:~/test$ lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no; mirror -R tmp/A_000/ /XXXXX/Y/ --dry-run ; bye" -u username,password remote_storage_url
mkdir -p ftp://username:password@remote_storage_url/%2F/XXXXX/Y/
To be removed: 0 directories, 11 files, 0 symlinks
```

I want file count to be added before I do actual upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mirror with the option --dry-run or —-script, then interpret the log.

Comment: Added mirror command stuff in my question in Edit-1 part